# Backbone not loading collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I started a fresh BackboneJS project and I implemented some simple code.
It isn't calling the right functions, I guess, I'm not seeing any errors and I'm also not seeing the expected `console.log` calls.

```
import _ from 'underscore';
import {Events} from 'backbone';
import Observables from './Models/Observables';
import ObservablesView from './Views/ObservablesView';

(function () {
    let setGlobals = function () {
        window.App = {};
        App.events = _.clone(Events);
    };

    let init = function () {
        setGlobals();

        // Get the collection from localStorage.
        let observables = new Observables();
        new ObservablesView({el: "#observables", collection: observables});

        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', init);
})();
```

This is my router:

```
import {Backbone} from 'backbone';
import {Router} from 'backbone';

const FedRouter = Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index'
    },

    index: function () {
        App.events.trigger('observables');
    }
});
export default FedRouter;
```

This is my view:

```
import {View} from 'backbone';
import FedRouter from "../FedRouter";

/**
 * ObservablesView is the list of items we want to keep track of.
 */
const ObservablesView = View.extend({
    router: null,

    /**
     * Init a new view object.
     * @constructor
     */
    initialize: function () {
        this.router = new FedRouter();
        App.events.on('observables', this.loadObservables, this);
    },

    loadObservables: function () {
        console.log("loadObservables");
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: (collection) => console.log(collection),
            error: (collection, response) => console.log(response)
        });
    }

});

export default ObservablesView;
```

My collection:

```
import {Backbone} from 'backbone';
import {Collection} from 'backbone';
import Observable from './Observable';
import Store from 'backbone.localstorage';

const Observables = Collection.extend({
    model: Observable,
    localStorage: new Store('fed-observables')
});

export default Observables;
```

And finally my model:

```
import {Model} from 'backbone';

const Observable = Model.extend({
});
export default Observable;
```

So how comes I'm not seeing the "loadObservables" message being logged. What am I not setting up right?

Comment: Is this statement executing fine?

window.addEventListener('load', init);

Because I feel, there is an issue with load event binding. 
Also, if you use jQuery, can you please try executing same with document.ready?

It is just a thought.

Comment: Maybe you have a filter applied in your console tat doesn't display normal logs. Could you create an [mcve] demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your routing is incorrect, everything else is fine, here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7y67ybd/)

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "_display/"});
```

This is the only change I had to make, due to the particular URL structure on JSFiddle. I suggest you debug the code and step into this `start` function, you'll likely end up in the [loadUrl](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-234) function, where you can see the fragment being evaluated.